# NodeJS application behind APache2 reverse proxy get error "413 Request Entity Too Large" on upload files

Tags: node.js, apache, file-upload, proxy, reverse-proxy

I work on a node.js application that permits its users to upload large files.

- When I run it on `8080` or `3000` or whatever, its okay.
- But when I access it on `80` behind apache2 with `mod_proxy` configured as reverse proxy, I get this error on upload (files > **1MB**)

> 413  Request Entity Too Large

I tryed to add this directive to apache config :

```
LimitRequestBody 0
```

But it doesn't change this behavior. I don't know where to search the right conf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

It seems Apache reverse Proxy works with `mod_proxy` but it also needs `mod_proxy_http`.

In my case all the application works fine with only the fisrt apart uploading files > 1MB.

I found references to `mod_proxy_http` and enabled it :

```
# a2enmod proxy_http
# apache2 restart
```

Now it seems work. I trying to upload larger and larger files to the server to test it. The last was 160MB and uploaded fine.